# An inequality relating to $L^2$ norms of the gradient of a harmonic polynomial

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

I am self-studying some PDE stuff, and the following inequality arose in a proof of the theorem, without any further explanations.

Let $U$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. By a Lipschitz domain, I mean the following.

> There exist constants $r_0 , M>0$ such that for each $z \in \partial U$, there exists a Lipschitz map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb R$ with $|\nabla \phi|_{L^\infty} \leq M$ with
> $$
> B(z,r_0) \cap U = B(z,r_0) \cap \big\{ \big(x,\phi(x)\big) : x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \big\}.$$

The inequality says that for any harmonic polynomial $f$ of degree $\leq d$,

> $$\int_{U_{2r}} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 dx \leq C \int_{U} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 dx$$

for a constant $C>0$ depending on $d$, $n$, $r$,  $N$, and $M$.
Here, $U_{2r} $ is the set of points whose distance from $U$ is less than $2r$.
$N$ denotes the number of open balls (as in the definition of "Lipschitz domain") which are required to cover $\partial U$.

I am lost since I do not see any reason for the inequality to be true. Could someone help me, please? Any bits of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Note: the statement in the question was used as the final step for a proof of the following inequality.

> $$|\nabla f|_{L^2 (\partial U)} \leq C_{d, n, r, N, M} |\nabla f|_{L^2(U)}$$

Comment: With your definition of $U_{2r}$, the inequality you are trying to demonstrate is certainly true by the continuity of the (Lebesgue) integral as a set function, but $C$ would be larger than $1$, since $U_{2r}\Supset U$. Is this really what you want?

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Maybe I am missing a basic point. Could you give an explanation in detail? (The constant $C$ must hold for all harmonic polynomial $f$ of degree $\leq d$.)

Comment: Since $U$ is Bounded (and so is $U_{2r}$), then $|\nabla f|$ is bounded on the domain you consider, and you can try to find an estimate for its supremum. If you succeed in finding it, then the inequality is a consequence of the continuity of the Lebesgue integral. Regarding the estimates of the supremum I thing a good route to find it would be to look for inequalities similar to [Bernstein's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_(polynomials)#Bernstein's_inequality).

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Surely I could try to estimate $\sup_{x \in U} |\nabla f(x)|$, but why does it imply that the integral on $U_{2r} - U$ is bounded by the integral on $U$? Sorry for my ignorance, but I am not sure what do you mean by "continuity of the Lebesgue integral"...

Comment: For the moment it is just an idea, but I note that $$\int_{U_{2r}} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 \mathrm{d}x = \left(1+\frac{\int_{U_{2r}\setminus {U}} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 \mathrm{d}x}{\int_{U} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 \mathrm{d}x}\right)\cdot\int_{U} | \nabla f(x)| ^2 \mathrm{d}x$$ Seen this, my idea is trying to estimate the the quotient of integrals inside the round brackets by using inequalities for polynomials and/or harmonic functions.

Comment: And I apologize for having used the (perhaps) obsolete phrase "continuity of the Lebesgue integral": it is a compact way of saying that  the value of the Lebesgue integral  (respect to an $AC$ measure like, for example, the Lebesgue measure) depends continuously on the measure of the domain where the integral is calculated.